# Fastest way to plot a line graph from a matrix in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

Is there a way I can speed up the following code to plot a line graph in R from a matrix? The matrix is quite big, around 3000 rows by 60 columns, sometimes the data is bigger.

I currently use `matlines` or `ggplot` for example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

## using ggplot2
data <- matrix(rnorm(3000*60), ncol = 60)
df <- as.data.frame(data)
df$id <- rownames(df)
plot_data <- melt(df, id.var = "id")
ggplot(plot_data, aes(x=variable,y=value,group=id)) + geom_point() + geom_line()


## using matlines
plot(0, ylim = range(data), xlim = c(1, ncol(data)), ylab = "tmp",
     type = "n", xaxt = "n", xlab = "")
axis(1, at = seq(ncol(data)), labels = colnames(data), las = 2)
matlines(t(data))
```

I used `Sys.time()` to get an idea of timings and it's pretty slow in both cases, around 22 seconds for `ggplot` and 24 seconds for `matlines`. I am building this into a Shiny app and it takes a very long time to render (similarly in the console).

Any help greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats4    parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] reshape2_1.4.4       ggplot2_3.3.1        circlize_0.4.9       shinyhelper_0.3.2    colorspace_1.4-1    
 [6] colourpicker_1.0     shinythemes_1.1.2    DT_0.13              shiny_1.4.0.2        dplyr_1.0.0         
[11] pRoloc_1.29.0        BiocParallel_1.22.0  MLInterfaces_1.68.0  cluster_2.1.0        annotate_1.66.0     
[16] XML_3.99-0.3         AnnotationDbi_1.50.0 IRanges_2.22.2       MSnbase_2.14.2       ProtGenerics_1.20.0 
[21] S4Vectors_0.26.1     mzR_2.22.0           Rcpp_1.0.4.6         Biobase_2.48.0       BiocGenerics_0.34.0
```

Comment: Half of that timing: `matplot(data, type = "l")`. R4.0.1, Windows 10.

Comment: Redesign your plot. Plotting 3000 lines can't be the optimal way of visualizing your data.

Comment: `boxplot(data)` runs in 1 second.

Comment: @Roland Your comment is well taken, but I can think of applications in my field where we might want to plot a large number of lines on the same plot, e.g. the plot here https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1303878-placebo-tests-for-synthetic-control-method

Comment: @WeihuangWong the graph you have linked to has two orders of magnitude less than 3000 lines. And it's still not a great way to visualize the data.

Comment: sorry @WeihuangWong ,how is your solution faster than matplot or matlines, it's the same thing underneath.. I find it quite hard to time functions that involve plotting.. do you think thats the issue?

Comment: @StupidWolf: thanks for your comment, it got me to do some more experiments. I realized the speedup was probably due to my "solution" having the same line color and type for all lines. `matlines` by default cycles through line types and colors, which (for reasons I don't understand) slows down the rendering. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Roland totally agree plotting 3000 lines in one go, on one plot is not particularly informative but this was the simplest way to explain my scenario. I will always plot subsets (tens of subsets) of these 3000 items by colour and likely split into multiple line plots.

Comment: Would it be an idea for your app to change the visualisation based on the sample size? Meaning, if only few IDs selected, plot every line, and from a certain threshold, simply show a random sample from the selected groups, or create predictions as suggested by Allan Cameron?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to decrease your rendering time by reducing the number of colors and linetypes in your plot. For example, compare default `matlines`, which cycles through 5 linetypes and 6 colors:

```
system.time({
  plot(0, ylim = range(data), xlim = c(1, ncol(data)), ylab = "tmp",
       type = "n", xaxt = "n", xlab = "")
  axis(1, at = seq(ncol(data)), labels = colnames(data), las = 2)
  matlines(t(data))
})
   # user  system elapsed 
   # 0.66    3.50    4.15
```

to one where we only use one linetype and one color

```
system.time({
  plot(0, ylim = range(data), xlim = c(1, ncol(data)), ylab = "tmp",
       type = "n", xaxt = "n", xlab = "")
  axis(1, at = seq(ncol(data)), labels = colnames(data), las = 2)
  matlines(t(data), col = 1, lty = 1)
})
   # user  system elapsed 
   # 0.23    0.58    0.83
```

As others have mentioned, other than the performance aspect, simplifying the plot may be good in and of itself.

Comment: With this number of overplotted lines, would a `geom_ribbon` be more effective?

Answer (score 1):

I just want to highlight how expensive drawing the points is if you have to draw a lot of them in ggplot2. Here are some different benchmarks with different types of points. If you omit the points you can draw the plot in 1/3rd of the time. Having periods `.` as points in 40% of the time. If you definitely need proper points, I recommend `shape = 16`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

data <- matrix(rnorm(3000*60), ncol = 60)
df <- as.data.frame(data)
df$id <- rownames(df)
plot_data <- melt(df, id.var = "id")

bm <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  baseline = {
    g <- ggplot(plot_data, aes(x=variable,y=value,group=id)) + 
      geom_point() + 
      geom_line()
    print(g)
  }, 
  nopoint = {
    g <- ggplot(plot_data, aes(x=variable,y=value,group=id)) + 
      geom_line()
    print(g)
  }, 
  periodpoint = {
    g <- ggplot(plot_data, aes(x=variable,y=value,group=id)) + 
      geom_point(shape = ".") + 
      geom_line()
    print(g)
  }, 
  shape16point = {
    g <- ggplot(plot_data, aes(x=variable,y=value,group=id)) + 
      geom_point(shape = 16) + 
      geom_line()
    print(g)
  }, 
  times = 10
)

df <- data.frame(
  x = bm$expr,
  y = bm$time / 1e9 # because measured in nanoseconds
)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, NA), name = "Time (s)")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

```r
devtools::session_info()
#> - Session info ---------------------------------------------------------------
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
#>  os       Windows 10 x64              
#>  system   x86_64, mingw32             
#>  ui       RTerm                       
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  English_United Kingdom.1252 
#>  ctype    English_United Kingdom.1252 
#>  tz       Europe/Berlin               
#>  date     2020-06-27                  
#> 
#> - Packages -------------------------------------------------------------------
#>  package        * version    date       lib source                            
#>  assertthat       0.2.1      2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  backports        1.1.7      2020-05-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  callr            3.4.3      2020-03-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  cli              2.0.2      2020-02-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  colorspace       1.4-1      2019-03-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  crayon           1.3.4      2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  curl             4.3        2019-12-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  desc             1.2.0      2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  devtools         2.3.0      2020-04-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  digest           0.6.25     2020-02-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  dplyr            0.8.5      2020-03-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  ellipsis         0.3.1      2020-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  evaluate         0.14       2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  fansi            0.4.1      2020-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  farver           2.0.3      2020-01-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  fs               1.4.1      2020-04-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  ggplot2        * 3.3.0.9000 2020-05-31 [1] Github (tidyverse/ggplot2@2b03e47)
#>  glue             1.4.1      2020-05-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  gtable           0.3.0      2019-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  highr            0.8        2019-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  htmltools        0.5.0      2020-06-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  httr             1.4.1      2019-08-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  knitr            1.28       2020-02-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  labeling         0.3        2014-08-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  lifecycle        0.2.0      2020-03-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  magrittr         1.5        2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  memoise          1.1.0      2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  microbenchmark   1.4-7      2019-09-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  mime             0.9        2020-02-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  munsell          0.5.0      2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  pillar           1.4.4      2020-05-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  pkgbuild         1.0.8      2020-05-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  pkgconfig        2.0.3      2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  pkgload          1.1.0      2020-05-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  plyr             1.8.6      2020-03-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  prettyunits      1.1.1      2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  processx         3.4.2      2020-02-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  ps               1.3.3      2020-05-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  purrr            0.3.4      2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  R6               2.4.1      2019-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  Rcpp             1.0.4.6    2020-04-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  remotes          2.1.1      2020-02-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  reshape2       * 1.4.4      2020-04-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  rlang            0.4.6      2020-05-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  rmarkdown        2.1        2020-01-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  rprojroot        1.3-2      2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  scales           1.1.1      2020-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  sessioninfo      1.1.1      2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  stringi          1.4.6      2020-02-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  stringr          1.4.0      2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  testthat         2.3.2      2020-03-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  tibble           3.0.1      2020-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  tidyselect       1.1.0      2020-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  usethis          1.6.1      2020-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  vctrs            0.3.0      2020-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  withr            2.2.0      2020-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  xfun             0.13       2020-04-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  xml2             1.3.2      2020-04-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  yaml             2.2.1      2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#> 
#> [1] D:/Users/teunv/Documents/R/win-library/4.0
#> [2] C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.0/library
```